# How To animate image using uibuttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, animation, sdk

I have three uibuttons named 1,2 and 3 and right at the bottom of those buttons i have an arrow image which indicates that which is the current button pressed.
I want that when i press any of the button the arrow starts animating and slides at the bottom of the button which is pressed.

Comment: what code have u written so far?

Answer (score 0):

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state;

and select UIControlState from

```
enum {
UIControlStateNormal       = 0,                       
UIControlStateHighlighted  = 1 << 0,                  // used when UIControl isHighlighted is set
UIControlStateDisabled     = 1 << 1,
UIControlStateSelected     = 1 << 2,                  // flag usable by app (see below)
UIControlStateApplication  = 0x00FF0000,              // additional flags available for application use
UIControlStateReserved     = 0xFF000000               // flags reserved for internal framework use
};
typedef NSUInteger UIControlState;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hook all your buttons up to one method or in the method that responds to each of the button clicks call this method as well.

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender;
{
    CGPoint center = self.indicator.center;
    center.x = sender.center.x;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                     animations:^{
                         self.indicator.center = center;
                     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following in your button pressed method:

```
// For Button 1
- (IBAction)pressedButton1:(id)sender{

        // Create an animation lasting 1 second
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.00];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

        // Set your arrow image view's center x property to that of the button
        myArrowImageView.center = CGPointMake(myButton1.center.x, myArrowImageView.center.y);

        [UIView commitAnimations];

}

// For Button 2
- (IBAction)pressedButton2:(id)sender{

    // Create an animation lasting 1 second
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.00];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    // Set your arrow image view's center x property to that of the 2nd button
    myArrowImageView.center = CGPointMake(myButton2.center.x, myArrowImageView.center.y);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

// For Button 3
- (IBAction)pressedButton3:(id)sender{

    // Create an animation lasting 1 second
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.00];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    // Set your arrow image view's center x property to that of the 3rd button
    myArrowImageView.center = CGPointMake(myButton3.center.x, myArrowImageView.center.y);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

P.S. its always good to also post some source code when you ask a question. This helps people to give you a better answer.

Comment: You cannot assign `center.x` like that you will get an `Expression is not assignable warning`